# If number is represented by '#' what represents text?

Tags: symbols

Numbers are represented commonly by '#' but I fail to see any sign that represents text. Is there any sign/symbol that indicates it should be in text (or text format)?

Comment: Numbers are a limited form of text. Text is assumed by default.

Comment: This kind of question might be on-topic at [ux.se] or [graphicdesign.se] (typography tag.)

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such symbol.

`#5`

["number 5"]

We have no such symbol that would go where the question mark is below:

**?** F

to indicate "the letter F"  as distinct from hexadecimal F, say.  Text is the default.

Since you used the phrase "should be in text":

On data-entry forms, the mask `#####` has conventionally indicated that a numeric value is required, and the underscore mask `_____________` that an alphanumeric would be accepted, since the day of character-mode terminals and monitors.

Comment: Alternatively, `XXXXX` is not uncommon, either.

Answer (score 0):

You can use asterix also.

*

This is usually used as a wild-card for unknown characters.